# equivalent java library required for curl- to submit forms to remote web sites

Tags: java, php, curl

I have a php web application that asks the user for all fields' values (all fields for a web form) and then shows only captcha and multiple choice values of that form on screen, the end user has to fill in these values and then the form is submitted to its action. The operative part of the php code uses curl for this operation. That php code is given below-

```
    $page = $curl->post($submit_url, array(
    'TITLE'   => $urltitle,
    'URL' => $urlurl,
    'OWNER_NAME' => $urlname,
    'OWNER_EMAIL' => $urlemail,
    'CATEGORY_ID' =>  $CATEGORY_ID,
    'RECPR_URL' => '',
    'IMAGEHASH' => $hash,
    'LINK_TYPE' => $dfln,
    'CAPTCHA' => $captcha,
    'AGREERULES' => 'on',
    'submit'    => 'Continue'
));
```

My question is, is there a library in Java that can do the same thing? I plan to submit same/similar data to many web forms, if this can be done in java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `java.net.HttpURLConnection` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/2793153#2793153)
- [apache http components](http://hc.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Apache HttpClient:

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

And the tutorial is here: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html